# Skip Navigation is not working in new opened window of firefox but it works in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, navigation

when i open a new window using window.open in firefox and try to navigate different section of the page within the new window using skip navigation does not work and preview window get reloaded.here is what i am doing.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function openWindow()
        {
            var win = window.open("","_blank");
            win.document.write("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><a href='#rajeev'>hi</a><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><div id='rajeev'>To Come Here</div></html>");
            win.document.close();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="openWindow()">Display Date</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Quentin: here is the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/drwkm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add the following onclick code to you link, instead of the hash:

```
onclick='$(document).scrollTop($(\"#rajeev\").offset().top);'
// Escaped the quotes since it will be placed in a document.write("");
```

You'll need to import jQuery in the popup's code, but if I just use this:

```
`win.document.write("<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js' type='text/javascript'></script>`
```

The browser seems to interpret the `</script>` tag as the end tag for the whole "popup-writing" script.
This can be circumvented by cutting up the `</script>` tag in the strings, as seen below.

[This code](http://jsfiddle.net/4ypFq/4/) works for me in Firefox and Chrome:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function openWindow()  {
                var win = window.open("","_blank");
                win.document.write("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js' type='text/javascript'></scr");
                // Split up the </script> tag.
                win.document.write("ipt></head><body><a  onclick='$(document).scrollTop($(\"#rajeev\").offset().top);'>hi</a><br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br><div id='rajeev'>To Come Here</div></html>");
                win.document.close();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="openWindow()">Display Date</button>
    </body>
</html>​
```

Now, you will only need to style the `<a>` to make it look like you can click it, or replace it with a `<button>`, for example.

<sup>(Stackoverflow kinda messes up the syntax highlighting in the code above, but it's valid js. Also, you generally don't want to add inline event listeners in your HTML.)</sup>

Comment: No it is not working in firefox. you can check your fiddle example in firefox. Everytime i click on "hi", insteading setting focus to "To Come Here", page is reloaded to earlier window where "Display Date" button is present. It works fine in IE and chrome but has an issue in Firefox

Comment: This appears to be a browser issue. Both Chrome and IE(!!!) behave as expected. I am indeed seeing the same problem in Firefox. adding a `onclick='return false' or onclick='preventDefault'` only prevents the link from doing anything at all.

Comment: what is solution? i didnt want to use separate pages.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, this (the last block in my answer) is the same code as your example, only the button now works in firefox, too.

Comment: i am not able to get that. Can you show this in fiddler please

Comment: Ok i got that. But i had around 100 or more than that links in the page. so will that be fine to add like that. Is any other idea on that. Most of these links are auto generated so maybe id will changed everytime

Comment: Technically, you could add as many links as you want in the `document.write`, but I'd suggest using a separate file, then.